# C# SilverLight User Control - Custom Panel not presented on the Form (XAML.CS file)

Tags: c#, silverlight, panel, silverlight-5.0

I made very simple Silver Light User Control (Custom Panel) with one text box (named "field") and I am trying to present custom panel in the form but although class is triggered and I can see debug information ("Control Init 2" and "Control Load 2" are in  Debug output) but panel and textbox are not presented.

XAML.CS file is the following:

```
namespace CustomPanel2
{
    public partial class SilverlightControl1 : W6CustomPanelControlBase
    {
        public SilverlightControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Debug.WriteLine("Control Init 2");

        }

        private void LoadTest(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            field.Text = "aaa";
            Debug.WriteLine("Control Load 2");
        }
    }
}
```

XAML file has the following: `Loaded="LoadTest"`

XAML definition is the following:

```
<BaseClass:W6CustomPanelControlBase
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:BaseClass="clr-namespace:W6.Web.FormEngine.PropertyPanels;assembly=W6.Web.FormEngine"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk" x:Class="CustomPanel2.SilverlightControl1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400" Loaded="LoadTest">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <TextBox x:Name="field" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="40,135,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged" Background="#FF30E6D5" FontWeight="Bold"/>


    </Grid>
</BaseClass:W6CustomPanelControlBase>
```

Comment: Show your `xaml` part. And you should make your mind up whether you want to create a `Control` or a `Panel`, that's a huge difference. So this base class you are deriving from...is it a `Control` or a `Panel`?

Comment: Hi Martin I updated the code with XAML part. Please tell me if something is not defined properly

Comment: are you able to determine why panel is not presented? As I said when I turn on the Debugger output is written in the output

Comment: Two issues: first, I can see you're using something called `W6CustomPanelControlBase` - which isn't a standard `UserControl` typically used. Secondly, a `UserControl` isn't presented by default - it's presented as part of another page (and, as such, another XAML file). You've only given us one XAML file, so something doesn't add up.

Comment: If you don't provide informtion about that mysterious base class `W6CustomPanelControlBase` you won't get an answer.

Answer (score 1):

From the XAML you presented (as well as from the .cs code) I can see you're not using a typical `UserControl`. Instead you are using something called a `W6CustomPanelControlBase` from `W6.Web.FormEngine.PropertyPanels`.

What that is and how that works? I have no idea. Without knowing how it works it'll be difficult to tell you what you did wrong.

Also - typically a `UserControl` is displayed as part of another XAML - a `Page`, another `UserControl` or a `Frame`. The XAML code you posted is only the the user control itself, but not how it's shown - in other words - the problem might not lie with the user control itself but with how it's shown.